# HIVE INSERT INTO failing with Namespace Quota issue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using below Insert Query to insert the records into the HIVE ORC table and getting the Namespace quota issue. The actual quota assigned for the directory is 3495253 But during the insert operation, its getting exceeded by the internal process, and the job is getting failed. below are the configs used in Hive.

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set tez.queue.name=dbqueue;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.created.files=10000000;
set hive.tez.container.size=10240;
set hive.tez.min.partition.factor=0.25;
set hive.tez.max.partition.factor=2.0;
set hive.optimize.reducededuplication.min.reducer=4;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-server -Xmx8692m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:NewRatio=8 -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps;
set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100000;
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.merge.cardinality.check=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=false;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;

set hive.stats.autogather=false;
set hive.analyze.stmt.collect.partlevel.stats=false;

SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;

set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;

INSERT into db.final_table partition (part_column)
select s.col1,s.col2,s.col3,....,s.part_column from db.source_table s
;
```

Error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.NSQuotaExceededException): The NameSpace quota (directories and files) of directory <user-path> is exceeded: quota=3495253 file count=3495254
```

I tried with `set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399313/hive-approaching-namespace-quota-because-of-insert-into), but no luck.

Any hint to resolve this issue will be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the quota of a directory for HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489519/how-to-get-the-quota-of-a-directory-for-hdfs)

Comment: @1stenjoydmoment were you able to resolve the issue?